# how to config prettier

Tags: html, vue.js, format, prettier

automatic prettier,make my code like this.Anti-human!

```html
    <v-footer :absolute="!fixed" app
      ><span>&copy; {{ new Date().getFullYear() }}</span></v-footer
    >
```

how can i config to make code like follow format

```html
<v-footer :absolute="!fixed" app><span>&copy; {{ new Date().getFullYear() }}</span></v-footer>
```

suggest in
module.exports = {

}

ths

Comment: Try printWidth. You can move <span> to another line to avoid this. Prettier can't do this for you because this can potentially break the layout